# Sphere Ray Intersection

Tags: c++

Trying to do a Ray-Sphere intersection program using C++.

I'm having trouble understanding the parent function of C++. I am trying to use it with 3 variables but it isn't letting me. How else can I do it?

```
#include "Point3D.h"

Point3D::Point3D() :X{ 0 }, Y{ 0 }, Z{ 0 }{ }
Point3D::Point3D(double xP, double yP, double zP) :X{ xP }, Y{ yP }, Z{ zP } {}

Point3D::~Point3D(){
    this->X = 0;
    this->Y = 0;
    this->Z = 0;
}

double Point3D::getX(){
  return this->X;
}

double Point3D::getY(){
  return this->Y;
}

double Point3D::getZ(){
  return this->Z;
}

void Point3D::setX(double xP)
{
  this->X = xP;
}

void Point3D::setY(double yP)
{
  this->Y = yP;
}

void Point3D::setZ(double zP)
{
  this->Z = zP;
}

Point3D& Point3D::addVectors(const Point3D& vec){
  this->X += vec.X;
  this->Y += vec.Y;
  this->Z += vec.Z;
}

Point3D& Point3D::subtractVectors(const Point3D& vec){
  this->X -= vec.X;
  this->Y -= vec.Y;
  this->Z -= vec.Z;
}

double Point3D::multiplyVectors(const Point3D& vec){
  double val = (this->X *vec.X) + (this->Y *vec.Y) + (this->Z *vec.Z);
  return val;
}

double Point3D::squareVector(){
  double val = (this->X) *(this->X) + (this->Y) * (this->Y) + (this->Z) * (this->Z);
  return val;
}

Point3D operator+(const Point3D &val1, const Point3D &val2, const Point3D &val3){
    return Point3D(val1.X + val2.X + val3.X,  val1.Y + val2.Y + val3.Y, val1.Z + val2.Z + val3.Z);
}

Point3D operator-(const Point3D &val1, const Point3D &val2, const Point3D &val3){
    return Point3D(val1.X - val2.X - val3.X, val1.Y - val2.Y - val3.Y, val1.Z - val2.Z - val3.Z);
}

Point3D operator*(const Point3D &val1, const Point3D &val2, const Point3D &val3){
  return Point3D(val1.X * val2.X * val3.X, val1.Y * val2.Y * val3.Y, val1.Z * val2.Z * val3.Z);
}
Point3D operator/(const Point3D &val1, const Point3D &val2, const Point3D &val3){
  return Point3D(val1.X / val2.X / val3.X, val1.Y / val2.Y / val3.Y, val1.Z / val2.Z / val3.Z);
}

Point3D operator- (const Point3D &val){
    return Point3D( -val.X, -val.Y, -val.Z);
}


bool operator!(const Point3D &val){

    cout << "Friend function is called!!!" << endl;
    return ( val.X != 0.0 || val.Y != 0.0 || val.Z != 0.0);
}

bool Point3D::operator!(){

    return ( ((*this).X != 0) || ((*this).Y != 0) || ((*this).Z != 0));
}


Point3D& Point3D::operator++(){

    cout << "Calling prefix ......." << endl;
    X += 1;
    Y += 1;
  Z += 1;
    return (*this);
}

Point3D& Point3D::operator++(int){
    cout << "Calling postfix ......." << endl;
    Point3D temp = *this;
    X += 1;
    Y += 1;
  Z += 1;
    return temp;

}

istream& operator>>(istream& istr, Point3D& P){
    istr >> P.X >> P.Y >> P.Z;
    return istr;
}

ostream& operator<<(ostream& ostr, Point3D& P){
    ostr << P.X << " " << P.Y << " " << P.Z;
    return ostr;
}
```

Main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Point3D.h"
using std::istream; using std::ostream;
int main(){

    Point3D P1, P2, P3;

    cout << "Enter the first point: " << endl;
    cin >> P1;
    cout << endl;

    cout << "Enter the second point: " << endl;
    cin >> P2;
    cout << endl;

  cout << "Enter the third point: " << endl;
  cin >> P3;
  cout << endl;

    cout << "Point P3 is: " << !P3;
    cout << "Points are: " << P1 << " and " << P2 << " and " << P3 << endl;

    Point3D P4, P5, P6, P7, P8;

    cout << "Point P8 is: " << P8  << endl;

    P4 = P1 + P2 + P3;
    P5 = P1 - P2 - P3;
    P6 = P1*P2*P3;
    P7 = P1 / P2 / P3;

    Point3D P30 = operator-(P1);
    operator << (cout, P30) << endl;

    cout << (cout, P30) << endl;
    cout << "Point P4 is: " << P4 << endl;
    cout << "Point P5 is: " << P5 << endl;
    cout << "Point P6 is: " << P6 << endl;

    Point3D P9 = P8.operator++();
    cout << "Point P8 is: " << P8 << endl;
    cout << "Point P9 is: " << P9 << endl;
    Point3D P10 = P8++;
    cout << "Point P8 is: " << P8 << endl;
    cout << "Point P10 is: " << P10 << endl;


    if (operator!(P1))  cout << "I'm not equal!!\n";

    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `C` and `C++` are different languages. Please only use the relevant tag.

Comment: That C snuck in there. Fixed it now

Comment: The problem is not very clear as it is described in the post. Are you talking about the operator! function? When you mention the three arguments, are you talking about the implementation in the header file?